# Installation of OpenSMILE 2.3.0

Tags: gcc, installation, clang

I am trying to configure OpenSMILE 2.3.0 on my Mac OS. Right now my only guess to why it's not working is that the Xcode syntax changed and OpenSMILE didn't catch up with it, so perhaps I need an older version of Xcode. Please let me know if it could be anything else.

I tried the suggestions from the other question ([MacOS: configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736091/macos-configure-error-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables)) and so far it has failed to configure still.

I tried downloading the latest Xcode command line tools to get the latest C compiler.

Command run:

`bash buildStandalone.sh`

Result:

```
- aclocal.
- autoconf.
- autoheader.
- automake.
- glibtoolize
- aclocal.
- autoconf.
- autoheader.
- automake.
- glibtoolize
./configure --without-portaudio --prefix=/Users/monica/music-emotion/opensmile-2.3.0/inst --enable-static --enable-shared=no
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/monica/music-emotion/opensmile-2.3.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
failed to configure openSMILE!
```

And config.log contains this:

```
## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2496: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2564: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2575: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2630: result: yes
configure:2781: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2820: result: ./install-sh -c -d
configure:2827: checking for gawk
configure:2843: found /usr/local/bin/gawk
configure:2854: result: gawk
configure:2865: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2887: result: yes
configure:2916: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:2933: result: yes
configure:3110: checking for gcc
configure:3126: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:3137: result: gcc
configure:3366: checking for C compiler version
configure:3375: gcc --version >&5
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
configure:3386: $? = 0
configure:3375: gcc -v >&5
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
configure:3386: $? = 0
configure:3375: gcc -V >&5
clang: error: unsupported option '-V -Wno-framework-include-private-from-public'
clang: error: no input files
configure:3386: $? = 1
configure:3375: gcc -qversion >&5
clang: error: unknown argument '-qversion', did you mean '--version'?
clang: error: no input files
configure:3386: $? = 1
configure:3406: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3428: gcc -O2 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -D__STATIC_LINK -DOPENSMILE_BUILD -DBUILD_SVMSMO -DBUILD_SVMSMO -DBUILD_LIBSVM -DBUILD_RNN -DBUILD_WITHOUT_EXPERIMENTAL -lrt -lm -lpthread -lc conftest.c  >&5
ld: library not found for -lrt
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
configure:3432: $? = 1
configure:3470: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "openSMILE"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "opensmile"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.3.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "openSMILE 2.3.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "opensmile"
| #define VERSION "2.3.0"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
|
| int
| main ()
| {
|
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3475: error: in `/Users/monica/music-emotion/opensmile-2.3.0':
configure:3477: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MacOS: configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736091/macos-configure-error-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables)

Answer (score 0):

If you edit `buildStandalone.sh` as follows:

```
-export LDFLAGS="-lm -lpthread -lc"
+export LDFLAGS="-lrt -lm -lpthread -lc"
```

it should work.  From what I can tell from elsewhere librt isn't need on OS-X.

Comment: The next problem you're likely to run into is: https://github.com/naxingyu/opensmile/issues/10#issuecomment-441281033